Question about technical characteristics needed to run experiment with Psychopy and Pupil Capture Builder
I am running an experiment with the abovementioned programs. Specifically, I have a loop with video stimuli. The size of these stimuli is 2,34 GB.
Unfortunatelly, running together Pupil Capture and Psychopy terminates the flow of my experiment before entering the loop (after the calibration and calibration routines in Psychopy).
Removing the eye-tracking components from the flow ended entering the loop with video stimuli, but disrupted after the presentation in some of them (6-10 of 38).
So I think that there is a problem in the specs of my PC (16 GB RAM, AMD Ryzen 3 2200U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 2.50 GHz CPU, AMD Radeon 3 Vega Graphics, OS Windows 10 64 bit, 164 GB SSD)
How should I upgrade my PC to run the whole experiment undisrupted?
Is there any solution methodologically to dicrease the demands of my experiment? I already have thought to break the stimuli to blocks, but there is no methodological reason to do it.
Thank you in advance for your time!
Removing the eye-tracking components from the flow ended entering the loop with video stimuli, but disrupted after the presentation in some of them (6-10 of 38).
Removing videos from my loop.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
